# JQPlot - Pie chart - get the clicked slice colour

Tags: jquery, jqplot

my requirement is to get the selected colour of the pie slice when the user clicks on it.
It would be good if I can do it within the following function:

```
$('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick',
    function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
      alert("ev = " + ev + " seriesIndex = " + seriesIndex + "pointIndex = " + pointIndex + "data = " + data);
});
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can get the color :

```
plot.series[seriesIndex].seriesColors[pointIndex]
```

where `plot` is the var in which you store your jqPlot

[Working Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/NYewy/15/)

Comment: +1 good one. Thanks for forking my sample :) Nice to see people reusing it.

Comment: @Boro i removed a few of the comments to try and make it easier to show the OP the code i added ... nice example though

Comment: @ManseUK Could you please tell me how to do this incase I want the legend name associated with that color?

Comment: @SilentPro if you have a question please ask one ... comments are not for asking further questions !